# Table dimensions in CSS not working in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

Im not able to get my data as expected in the table format.

```js
myList = '[{"date":"2020-04-05 18:26:01", "symptom":{"chest_pain":{"type":"Mild"},"cough":{"frequency":"5 to 15 times an hour","type":"With Flum"}}},{"date":"2020-04-06 14:57:11", "symptom":{"fever":{"temperature":"98"},"digestion_problem":"Yes"}},{"date":"2020-04-13 04:04:25", "symptom":{"cough":{"frequency":"Less than 5 times an hour","type":"Dry"},"breathing":{"severity":"6"}}}]';

function buildHtmlTable(selector) {
    var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList, selector);

    for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        var row$ = $('<tr/>');
        for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {

            var cellValue = getCellValue(myList[i], columns[colIndex]);
            if (cellValue == null)
                cellValue = "";
            row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
        }
        $(selector).append(row$);


    }
    $('th').each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).text(text.replace(/symptom/g, "")); 
        text = $(this).text();
        $(this).text(text.replace(/-/g, " ")); 
        text = $(this).text();
        $(this).text(text.replace(/_/g, " ")); 
        text = $(this).text();
        $(this).text(capitalizeFirstLetter(text)); 
    });
}

function capitalizeFirstLetter(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
  }

  console.log(capitalizeFirstLetter('foo')); // Foo


function addAllColumnHeaders(myList, selector) {
    var columnSet = [];
    var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

    for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        var rowHash = myList[i];

        recursiveHeaderCheck(rowHash, selector, "", columnSet, headerTr$);
    }
    $(selector).prepend("<thead>");
    $(selector).append(headerTr$);
    $(selector).append("</thead>");

    return columnSet;
}
```

```css
#symptom_table{
  width: 85vw !important;
  height: 50vh !important;
}

#excelDataTable  {
  width: 85vw !important;
  height: 50vh !important; 
}
```

```html
<div id="symptom_table"> 
     <table class="fl-table" id="excelDataTable" border="none"> </table>
  </div>
```

Im trying to display a table i fetched from my DB in HTML.

however, When i load my page and inspect, i dont see the table.
I see there is a mismatch in my dimensions. Data table contains data as well.

Not sure what im missing

Edit 1:
After changing - to _, . to # and wh to vh.
symptom_table
[image]
exceldatatable
[image]

Edit 2: 
I can see data from my js in my console:
[image]

Comment: `50vh`, not `50wh`.

Comment: You have a table with an **id symptom_table** - but you use a **class symptom-table** in your CSS. Underscore vs hive and id vs class.

Comment: @Azametzin 50vh has been made, no luck.

Comment: @Daniel, ive changes the _ changed, no change i still cant see the table

Comment: I would suggest you to prepare a running version of your code on codepen or jsfiddle. It would be easier to understand your issue

Comment: @dario, Ive dropped it as a snippet here.

Comment: myList is a string, I guess you want to be an array, so remove the `'` ; `recursiveHeaderCheck` , `getCellValue` are not defined

Comment: the value from myList basically is coming from my DB, i added a sample json for example. @Dario also my console shows 3 rows being reterived, it means i have data loaded right?

Comment: @Dario, i believe the issue is with the CSS since my JS provides an output on my console, just not displaying them.

Comment: The table in your screenshot has no headers, rows, columns. I doubt this is some CSS issue. Please post some code which runs without throwing error otherwise it is hard to understand the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS does not match the ID of your table: `.symptom-table` class is not applied to div having ID `symptom_table` (note `-` and `_`). 
I think you need to change `.symptom-table` selector to `#symptom_table`, that is selecting your table by ID with right spelling.

Also, fix the unit from `wh` to `vh`

Comment: i changed it to _, but i can still not see my table coming up.

Comment: From your screenshot, the table is there, you just don't see it cause it contains no data/rows, so there is nothing to render/see. But this is not due to any CSS

Comment: I can see the data being available (3 rows) in my console when i look through.

Comment: Also there are 2 things to change: `-` to `_` and `.` to `#` in your selector

Comment: I changed the same, updated images in my question, is there something im missing in my #exceldatatable?

Comment: I think you need to post some js. How do you expect the empty HTML table to have the rows/data you see in the console?

Comment: added the js and my console output which shows 3 rows of data. @Dario